# Appending more CTParagraphStyleSetting's in subclasses

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, core-text

I have an app where I use the `CoreText` libraries to format some text. I use the following to set the style settings:

```
- (void) setAttributes
{
    CTTextAlignment alignment = self.alignment;
    CGFloat spacing = self.spacing;

    CTParagraphStyleSetting paragraphSettings[] =  
    {
        {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment, sizeof(CTTextAlignment), &alignment}, 
        {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineSpacing, sizeof(CGFloat), &spacing},
    };

    CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(paragraphSettings, 2);
    [self.text addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName value:(id)paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [self.text.mutableString length])];
}
```

Then I have a subclass which has some different functionality that needs to add some more paragraphstyle settings:

```
- (void) setAttributes
{
    [super setAttributes];
    CGFloat firstLineHeadIndent = 11, headIndent = 11, tailIndent = -11, paragraphSpacing = 0, paragraphSpacingBefore = 0;

    CTParagraphStyleSetting paragraphSettings2[] =  
    {
        {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierFirstLineHeadIndent, sizeof(CGFloat), &firstLineHeadIndent},
        {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierHeadIndent, sizeof(CGFloat), &headIndent},
        {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierTailIndent, sizeof(CGFloat), &tailIndent},
        {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierParagraphSpacing, sizeof(CGFloat), &paragraphSpacing},
        {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierParagraphSpacingBefore, sizeof(CGFloat), &paragraphSpacingBefore}
    };

    CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle2 = CTParagraphStyleCreate(paragraphSettings2, 5);
    [self.text addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName value:(id)paragraphStyle2 range:NSMakeRange(0, [self.text.mutableString length])];
}
```

The problem with this is it isn't working because the second set of `CTParagraphStyleSetting's` is overwriting the first. What would be the correct way to go about doing this, I've tried numerous things, doing the `paragraphStyles` individually, and adding the attributes individually to the `attributedString`, but can't get anything to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call super, you will have set the paragraph style settings already as an attribute. Get the same attribute again, construct a new paragraph style with those settings, overriding some of the settings with new values as you'd like and finally set this new paragraph style as an attribute.